# What is the best option to run tensorflow-lite in flutter?

Tags: tensorflow, flutter, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite

In the Napur Garg's talk at TFWorld'19, she mentioned about some community language bindings.

What is the more stable and reliable option for using TF-lite in Flutter for iOS and Android ?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flutter doesn't have built-in Tensorflow Lite integration.

You can either make your own Flutter plugin and implement native solution for iOS and Android. You would need to use channels to make communication between the Flutter and platform code.

More instuctions here: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages

But for TFLite there is already one such package made:
https://pub.dev/packages/tflite

I made an app with it and it works fine for image classification.

Answer (score 6):

You can use https://pub.dev/packages/tflite_flutter. It provides a dart API similar to the TfLite JAVA API.

[TFLite Flutter Helper Library](https://pub.dev/packages/tflite_flutter_helper) was also available but it's not discontinued.